# Having trouble with Entry variables in tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x650")
e = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Verdana', 30), justify='right')

a = b = c = e

a.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
b.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
c.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
root.mainloop()
```

Why can't I see all three entries, where are they?

But when I do this:

```
a = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Verdana', 30), justify='right')
b = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Verdana', 30), justify='right')
c = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Verdana', 30), justify='right')
```

it works...

Comment: Yeah, You will have to explain harder than that because I don't understand what the problem is in my code. I understand your answer perfectly but I still don't understand what exactly is wrong in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I see all three entries, where are they?

You can't see three entries because you didn't create three entries. When you do `a = b = c = e`, you are assigning three new names to the same object that `e` refers to, you aren't creating new widgets. `a`, `b`, `c`, and `e` all refer to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make "e" a class instead, and declare your boxes individually, a = b = e gives about the same result than what you tried.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x650")

class MyEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=root):
        Entry.__init__(self, master=root)

        self.configure(width = 3, 
            font = ('Verdana', 30),
            justify = 'right')

a = MyEntry()
b = MyEntry()
c = MyEntry()

a.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
b.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
c.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
root.mainloop()
```